# Access child variable from an include in parent template

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to specify a variable in a child template and access it from another template which is included in the parent template.

Here's what I'm trying to do (code trimmed to the bare minimum):

**child.html**

```
{% set var = 'foo' %}
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% include 'bar.html' %}
```

**bar.html**

```
{{ var }}
```

At this point, I render the `child.html` file and nothing is output.

### This is what I've tried:

If I specify the variable in the `base.html` file instead of the `child.html` file, it works.

If I pass the variable in my render call, it works. `template.render(var = 'foo')`

Chaging the base.html file to be `{% include 'bar.html' with context %}` doesn't fix it.

I am able to access the variable in my base.html file just fine, and in fact, I've managed to create a workaround by adding `{% set foo = var %}` to my base.html, and changing bar.html to `{{ foo }}`

So concisely put, my question is: Is there a way for a template that's included in a parent template to access a variable set in a child template? (Without having to define a new variable in the parent file like my workaround)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this by passing the variable within the child block on the parent template.

Ex. I have `active_page` declared on my child template `pricing.html`.

At first, I was not able to access `active_page` within my included file `navbar-alt.html` but when I set the variables inside of the navbar block it worked.

```
{% block wrapper %}
<div id="wrapper">
    {% block navbar %}
        {% set navigation_bar = [
            ('/what-we-do', 'what-we-do', 'what we do'),
            ('/pricing', 'pricing', 'pricing'),
            ('/demo', 'demo', 'demo'),
            ('http://indico.readme.io/v1.0/docs', 'docs', 'docs')
        ] -%}
        {% set active_page = active_page|default('index') -%}

        {% if "dashboard" not in request.path %}
            {% include 'includes/navbar-alt.html' %}
        {% else %}
            {% include 'includes/navbar.html' %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock navbar %}

    {% if "dashboard" in request.path %}
        {% block sidebar %}
            {% include 'includes/sidebar.html' %}
        {% endblock sidebar %}
    {% endif %}

    {% block content_wrapper %}
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </div>
    {% endblock content_wrapper %}
    {% include 'includes/flashes.html' %}
</div>
{% endblock wrapper %}
```

Original inspiration:
[Jinja Tricks](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/#highlighting-active-menu-items)